# Como o app GPS locker ou similares funciona?

Tags: android, gps

Estou desenvolvendo um app em Android, que monitora o caminho percorrido de uma máquina no campo, com isso preciso que os pontos do GPS venham fixo e mais precisos, coisa que somente o GPS Locker consegue fazer, porém não gostaria de ficar dependendo dele, gostaria de colocar dentro do app que estou desenvolvendo!

Comment: Seja bem-vindo ao StackOverflow em Português. Uma boa prática para iniciarmos uma discussão saudável é ler o [Guia de Como Perguntar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/asking). Comece seguindo estas recomendações, principalmente sabendo quais os tipos de perguntas deve fazer, como criar um exemplo mínimo que seja completo e verificável e até mesmo o que fazer quando alguém te responder.

Comment: O que você quer dizer com "*os pontos do GPS venham fixo e mais precisos*"? Fixo em qual sentido? Qual nível de precisão?